# How to load pages via ajax caching the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, optimization

I have to load the sections of my web dinamically, so as I want to load the content only one time I did one `<div>` for each page:

```
<a href="#" data-pageindex="0">Home</a>
<a href="#" data-pageindex="1">Contact</a>
<a href="#" data-pageindex="2">Portfolio</a>

<div id="page-home"></div>
<div id="page-contact"></div>
<div id="page-portfolio"></div>
```

Then I thought in something like this to do the ajax call (the point in this case is reduce the HTTP requests putting all the code of each section (initialitation of plugins mostly) in the same file):

```
$("[data-pageindex]").on("click", function(e){
    var index = parseInt($(this).data("pageindex"));

    $("nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    load_section(index);

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

function load_section(index_load){

    // 'urls' is an array with all the section names.
    var id_section = "#page-" + urls[index_load]; 

    if (! isEmpty( $(id_section) ) ){
        return;
    }

    console.log(id_section);

    switch(index_load){
        case 0: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/home.html", load_home); break;
        case 1: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/contact.html", load_contact); break;
        default: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/portfolio.html", load_portfolio);
    }
}
```

And here I have the callback functions where I execute the code for each section:

```
function load_home(){
    // 180 lines of code
}

function load_contact(){
    // 104 lines of code
}

function load_portfolio(){
    // 95 lines of code
}
```

It works, but I don't think is the best way to do it. 
Would be better use `$.getScript()` function instead of the code above?
You have any clearer alternative to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution works fine. You can cache the loaded templates in a hashmap and add one more level of indirection:

```
var templateCache = {};

function load_section(index_load) {
    // 'urls' is an array with all the section names.
    var id_section = "#page-" + urls[index_load]; 
    if (! isEmpty( $(id_section) ) ){
        return;
    }

    var url, callback;

    switch(index_load){
        case 0: url = "/application/ajax/home.html"; callback = load_home; break;
        case 1: url = "/application/ajax/contact.html"; callback = load_contact; break;
        default: url = "/application/ajax/portfolio.html"; callback = load_portfolio;
    }
    handleSection(id_section, url, callback);
}

function handleSection(id_section, section, callback) {
    if (templateCache[section]) {
        callback(templateCache[section]);
        return;
    }
    $(id_section).load(section, function (template) {
       templateCache[section] = template;
       callback.call(null, template);
    });
}
```

Similar caching strategy is used in AngularJS by the service `$templateCache`.

Comment: Thanks Minko! But I don't understand why the callback has argumments. My functions doesn't. Could you explain the handleSection() function line by line, please? :)

Comment: It just get the page and cache it if it isn't already cached.

Comment: Yes, I understand the main idea, but here: `callback(templateCache[section]);` the callback pass an argument. And my functions load_home(), load_portfolio() and load_contact() haven't got any arguments. I'd like to know why?

Comment: I see, I made a quick fix in my answer. As far as I see you want to pass the template (the page HTML) to `load_home`, `load_portfolio` and `load_contact`. I just pass this template. Callback actually is one of these three functions. I tried to keep the code a little DRY-er.

Comment: And what if i use delegated events? https://api.jquery.com/delegate/ I wouldn't need the callbacks to initialize. What do you think?

Comment: I think the use of the callback is fine. How you plan to use `delegate` (also better use `on` instead)?